# How to get user name and password from url in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, url

How can get in ASP.NET user name and password from URL?

```
https://myUser:myPassword@myServer/
```

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` is returning `https://myServer/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to access the authentication headers.

Info about HTTP Authentication:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Implementing it in asp.net:
http://blog.smithfamily.dk/2008/08/27/ImplementingBasicAuthenticationInASPNET20.aspx

Comment: The second link on this is broke.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's perfectly possible to have URI credentials in the URL without a HTTP Authorization header. To pull those out, since the Request.Url property is a Uri object, you can access those details in the Uri.UserInfo property.

Comment: It seems that IIS is not passing `UserInfo` to `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`.